# mongo $slice query reverse index out of range

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The following query in mongo, behaves strange :

```
db.items.findOne({},{ "List": { "$slice": [ skip, 3 ] }})
```

First:
Instead of returning one object with ["_id","List"] keys only, it returns a full object.

Second:
if `skip` is negative and `|skip|` is higher than list.length then it returns the first three elements as though `skip==0`

I would expect for:

```
{
       "_id" : ObjectId("542babf265f5de9a0d5c2928"),
       "List" : [
                1,
                2,
                3,
                4,
                5
        ]
        "other" : "not_important"
}
```

query:

```
db.items.findOne({},{ "List": { "$slice": [-10, 3 ] }})
```

to get:

```
{
       "_id" : ObjectId("542babf265f5de9a0d5c2928"),
       "List" : []
}
```

instead, I get:

```
{
       "_id" : ObjectId("542babf265f5de9a0d5c2928"),
       "List" : [
                1,
                2,
                3
        ]
        "other" : "not_important"
}
```

Why?

I use mongoDB 2.4.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Second: if skip is negative and |skip| is higher than list.length then it returns the first three elements as though skip==0*

Yes. That is how the javascript `Array.prototype.slice()` method works, which is internally used by mongodb.

According to the [ECMAScript® Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.10),

> If relativeStart is negative, let k be max((len + relativeStart),0); 
>   else let k be min(relativeStart, len).

In your case `relativeStart is -10`, 
`k = max((-10+5),0), k = 0;` (where, `5` is the length of your array).

Hence `k` or `skip` will always be `0`, in these cases.

> *First: Instead of returning one object with ["_id","List"] keys only, it returns a full object.*

Yes, the projection operator works that way. Unless a `inclusion` or `exclusion` is explicitly specified in the projection parameter, the whole document is retrieved with the projection operators such as `$slice`,`$elemmatch` being applied.

```
db.items.findOne({},{"_id":1,"List": { "$slice": [-10, 3 ] }})
```

would return:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("542babf265f5de9a0d5c2928"), "List" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
```

The second parameter to the `findOne()` method is `not only for simple projection` purpose, fields are **not** projected, only if any one of the `field` names have a value of `0` or `1` against them. If not the whole document is returned. If any field has a `projection operator` to be applied, it would be `applied` and `projected`.

The projection mechanism *seems* to happen in the below manner, whenever the `$slice` operator is involved.

- By default all the fields would be included for projection.
- By Default all the fields whose values are derived based on the projection operator, `$slice`, **if truthy**, are always displayed, irrespective of the below.

### Steps taking place for exclusion or inclusion.

- The list of fields specified in the projection parameter are accumulated in their specified order.
- **For only the first field encountered with value '0' or '1'**: 
  If the
  field  has a value '0' - then it is excluded, and all the remaining
  fields are marked to be included.
  If a field has '1' - then it is included, and all the remaining fields
  are marked to be excluded.
- For all the subsequent fields, they are excluded or included based on
  their values.

Comment: Well, I should have guessed that it's the js prototype implementation...
As for the projection, I can't see that anywhere in the documentation. At least for me, it doesn't sound reasonable unless you split it to 2 different declarations...

Comment: @skme, yes the nature of the projection parameter is not specified anywhere in the documentation, it was just after some test cases i was able to figure it out. The inclusion of projection operators make it a bit complicated.

Comment: @BatScream, your answer is helpful and basically I agree with the reasoning process about projection. But, actually `$elemMatch` has the different behavior to `$slice`. You can try `db.items.findOne({},{"List": { "$elemMatch": {$gte:1} }})`, `db.items.findOne({},{"_id":1,"List": { "$elemMatch": {$gte:1} }})` and `db.items.findOne({},{"_id":0,"List": { "$elemMatch": {$gte:1} }})`.

Comment: @Wizard, I'm not sure what you mean. The `$elemMatch` operator has completely different behavior and use than `$slice`. It's not used for paging but for querying on the array elements. The query you wrote will be good for a sorted numbers array but that wasn't the question. The question is for general paging when you want to retrieve arrays by reverse indexing.

Comment: @skme, I wrote the comment to BatScream. You can find there is a statement in the answer: `the whole document is retrieved with the projection operators such as $slice,$elemmatch being applied.` But these two operators have different behaviors on projection.

Comment: @Wizard, yes, i noticed it too. If you see the way projection has been implemented in the native code, i.e c++, the projection behavior gets altered when these operators occur in the query. Just for reference, you could have a look into:https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/query/parsed_projection.cpp and
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/projection.cpp

Answer (score 1):

Whilst this behavior is by design for the [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) operator, it is possible since MongoDB 3.2 to evaluate this and alter the result with the aggregation operator for [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/):

Given the example documents:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5922846dbcf60428d0f69f6e"), "a" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5922847cbcf60428d0f69f6f"), "a" : [ 5, 6 ] }
```

If given a conditional expression to test against the length of the array with [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) and only perform the [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) when the reverse index was greater than or equal to that length, or otherwise return an empty array:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "a": {
      "$cond": {
        "if": { "$gte": [ { "$size": "$a" }, 4 ] },
        "then": { "$slice": [ "$a", -4, 2 ] },
        "else": { "$literal": [] },
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Then of course you get:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5922846dbcf60428d0f69f6e"), "a" : [ 1, 2 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5922847cbcf60428d0f69f6f"), "a" : [ ] }
```

So that is how you could get MongoDB to return a "slice" that acts in this way.

Comment: Nice, I am really happy that I dont need to do a `"a.4":{$exists:true}` check before I run the slice. Two questions, 1. performance wise, when I have an array of millions of IDs, will $size operator be slow? 2. Do you know  why javascript/mongo implemented this way?

Comment: @Will On the issue of performance the aggregation framework should be more or less on par with the same `$slice` operation in a standard projection. As to the "why", that's another and an entirely broad question. Rest assured that this is the convention in various language implementations and that each one would have borrowed from the other.