# Mongodb slice how to manage to return null when skip is bigger than the max size?

Tags: mongodb

I am having a problem when I am using [slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/).

Suppose I have an array property that contains 3 elements.
Slice(-4,2) on the property gives me last 2 items where I expect null to be returned.

Comment: This is by design. What do expect to be done about it?

Comment: @NeilLunn I am finding the slice(-4,2) to return last 2 items to be difficult to understand, Do you know why javascript/mongo implemented this way?

Comment: Added an answer to the [marked duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203217/mongo-slice-query-reverse-index-out-of-range) that shows how you can get MongoDB to do what you want it to do.